# Nifi Marklogic User is not allowed to read resource at internal/forestinfo

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I have roles below but when run MarkLogic NIFI it shows error "Nifi Marklogic User is not allowed to read resource at internal/forestinfo".  Am I missing some rest API roles?  Thanks

```
Roles:
qconsole-user
rest-reader-internal 
rest-writer-internal 
rest-extension-user
IRSDA-collection-readonly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit *-internal roles, which are intended to be internal and subject to change with each release. Try inheriting rest-reader and rest-writer instead, and also verify that you are on ML 9 or higher, as that endpoint does not exist in ML 8.